# Is it possible to create an ADOX catalog in memory and populate it?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, memory, datatable, ado.net

I tried creating one like this:

```
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Catalog catalog = new Catalog(stream);   // do I need to add more after this?

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                Table adoxTable = new Table();
                adoxTable.Name = dt.TableName;
                adoxTable.ParentCatalog = catalog;   // issue is here

                catalog.Tables.Append(table);
            }

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
```

However when I get to the line `adoxTable.ParentCatalog = catalog;` I get the exception: `The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.`

Do I need to add additional steps after creating the catalog in order to properly utilize it?

Comment: I have no idea what ADOX is. But do you need to open a connection? Perhaps `Catalog` exposes an `Open()` method?

Comment: No, but it has a `.Create()` method that takes a connection string and could then set `catalog.ActiveConnection` to that could `.Open()` but that would entail a physical location. I'm trying to do this all in memory.